# AsyncTask keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

/*  Whenever the asynctask executes the application always crashes. I ran this  asynctask in another file as a standalone and it works perfectly so I am not sure why it does not work with the other parts of my code.*/

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private int a=0;
private int b=0;
private int c=0;
private int d=0;
private int e=0;
private int f=0;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();



// url to get all policy list
private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.12/thesis/get_all_policy.php";
String[] policyID = new String[100];
String[] policyname = new String[100];
// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_POLICIES = "policylist";
private static final String TAG_PID = "Policy_Status";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "Policy_Name";
 //private static final String TAG_STATUS = "Policy_Status";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray product = null;

private final static String LOG_TAG = "DevicePolicyAdmin";
DevicePolicyManager AnguardDevicePolicyManager;
ComponentName AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin;
private CheckBox AnguardAdminEnabledCheckbox;
protected static final int REQUEST_ENABLE = 1;
protected static final int SET_PASSWORD = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_policy_admin);
    AnguardDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin = new ComponentName(this,
            MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);


    // Get listview
    //ListView lv = getListView();

    AnguardAdminEnabledCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    // Hashmap for ListView

    // Loading products in Background Thread

    new LoadPolicyList().execute();  //AsyncTask is executed

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isMyDevicePolicyReceiverActive()) {
        AnguardAdminEnabledCheckbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        AnguardAdminEnabledCheckbox.setChecked(false);
    }
    AnguardAdminEnabledCheckbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                             boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                        intent.putExtra(
                                DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                                AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin);
                        intent.putExtra(
                                DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                                getString(R.string.admin_explanation));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);
                       // new LoadPolicyList().execute();
                    } else {
                        AnguardDevicePolicyManager
                                .removeActiveAdmin( AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin);
                    }
                }
            });
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE:
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Enabling Policies Now");
                if(a==1)
                AnguardDevicePolicyManager.wipeData(1234566);
                if(b==1)
                AnguardDevicePolicyManager.setMaximumTimeToLock(AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin, 10L);
                if(c==1)
                AnguardDevicePolicyManager.setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe( AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin, 5);
                if(d==1)
                AnguardDevicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_COMPLEX);
                if(e==1)
                AnguardDevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin, true);
                boolean isSufficient =  AnguardDevicePolicyManager
                        .isActivePasswordSufficient();
                if (isSufficient) {
                    AnguardDevicePolicyManager.lockNow();
                } else {
                    Intent setPasswordIntent = new Intent(
                            DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
                    startActivityForResult(setPasswordIntent, SET_PASSWORD);
                    AnguardDevicePolicyManager.setPasswordExpirationTimeout(
                            AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin, 10000L);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
class LoadPolicyList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    // I used json in this part to get database information it works fine as a stand alone.
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Policies: ", json.toString());

        try{

            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                // products found
                // Getting Array of Policylist
                product = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POLICIES);


                // looping through All Policies
                for (int i = 0; i < product.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = product.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    //String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String status = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    policyID[i] = status;
                    policyname[i] = name;
                    Log.d(policyID[i], "This is the Policy's status");
                    Log.d(policyname[i], "This is the Policy Name");
                    if(name.equals("Policy1"))
                    {Log.d(name, "This is it");
                        Log.d(status, "This is it part 2 HOORAY");
                    }


                }

            }


        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


}

private boolean isMyDevicePolicyReceiverActive() {
    return  AnguardDevicePolicyManager
            .isAdminActive( AnguardDevicePolicyAdmin);
}


public static class MyDevicePolicyReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Anguard's Device Admin Disabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Anguard's Device Admin is now enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CharSequence disableRequestedSeq = "Requesting to disable Device Admin";
        return disableRequestedSeq;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Device password is now changed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        DevicePolicyManager localDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName localComponent = new ComponentName(context,
                MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);
        localDPM.setPasswordExpirationTimeout(localComponent, 0L);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onPasswordExpiring(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This would require API 11 an above
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Anguard's Device password is going to expire, please change to a new password",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        DevicePolicyManager localDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName localComponent = new ComponentName(context,
                MyDevicePolicyReceiver.class);
        long expr = localDPM.getPasswordExpiration(localComponent);
        long delta = expr - System.currentTimeMillis();
        boolean expired = delta < 0L;
        if (expired) {
            localDPM.setPasswordExpirationTimeout(localComponent, 10000L);
            Intent passwordChangeIntent = new Intent(
                    DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
            passwordChangeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(passwordChangeIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Password failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Access Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,
                "MyDevicePolicyReciever Received: " + intent.getAction());
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
  }


}
```

**ERROR LOGS**

```
05-26 23:39:53.380    1617-1631/com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
05-26 23:39:53.380    1617-1631/com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
05-26 23:39:53.390    1617-1631/com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2c91b20)
05-26 23:39:53.390    1617-1631/com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration, PID: 1617
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration.MainActivity$LoadPolicyList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:165)
            at com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration.MainActivity$LoadPolicyList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:155)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Comment: Post your error logs.

Comment: where is your postExecute,preExecute method??

Comment: I did not use them because I just simply wanted to get values from the database and store it in an array. In the standalone file i made i didn't have post and pre execute and it is working fine

Comment: No Response is return from URL "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0"    check your URL and hit it on browser

Comment: Null pointer exception here please check this code : MainActivity.java:165

Comment: The problem is in json parsing.You are trying to parse invalid json string.Print the json response and try online json parser to check the problem in string.

Comment: NULL Pointer Exception at doInBackground , Post your code.

Comment: @birds MY doinBackground code is already posted

Comment: JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);  json possible is null?

Comment: @birds That line works on my standalone code. I just don't understand why it work with my code as a whole.

Comment: try to debug these codes step by step, insert some breakpoints.

Comment: That's **null pointer exception**, getting raised from line number 165 in MainActivity!

Comment: Just debug buddy, its NPE.. and try the URL on browser also..u must be crazy to tell it works separately but not working as whole..

Comment: This post contains a lot of code. Post a [Minimal,Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think people have time to read your full code.

Answer (score 0):

in your log I saw the error :

> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration.MainActivity$LoadPolicyList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:165) at com.example.gregsiy.deviceadministration.MainActivity$LoadPolicyList.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:155) at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at

that mean line 165 in your `MainActivity` class has `null error`

I guess line 165 is one of below code

```
if(name.equals("Policy1"))
                {Log.d(name, "This is it");
                    Log.d(status, "This is it part 2 HOORAY");
                }
```

So you should check the value of `status` or `name` variable in this case

Update : (I guess `name` variable is `null`)

Hope it's helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If `status` was null, it would not cause a NullPointerException there.  It would just log null.

Comment: So did you think NullPointerException occur in `name` variable because 
inline `name.equals("Policy1")` ?

Comment: Honestly, I think that the NPE occurs at `Log.d("All Policies: ", json.toString());`, but there's not enough to go on currently to be sure.  The code is missing all of the imports, so you can't just count the lines.